# highcharts render black on ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

i'm trying to make real time data with highchart, but i'm tired following documentation and doesn't understand,
i'm use ajax refresh for solution.
when page reload first time, my chart rendered,
and when ajax do refresh/2000 millisecond, my chart rendered always black

**index.php**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function () {

            $('#src2').load('monitor.php').fadeIn("slow");

        }, 2000); // refresh setiap 00000 milliseconds

</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 120px; height: 220px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</head>
<body>
<div id="src2"></div>
```

**Monitor.php**

```
  <script >
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Interval Chart',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Cisco Wallboard',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage (%)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'SCR',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 100]
        }, {
            name: 'SL',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }]
    });
});
    </script>
```

check with firebug,
i didn't know this error : TypeError: ha is not a function

Comment: Which line is is producing this error? Also, why don't you follow [this tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-live-data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need not refresh whole page for highchart dynamic data update, take the reference of highcharts config object and just update the series data.

Comment: have tutorial links with database mysql ?